# Locate CUDA installation on Linux

Tags: linux, path, installation, cuda

What's the best way?
Here are my solutions:

```
echo $PATH | sed "s/:/\n/g" | grep "cuda/bin" | sed "s/\/bin//g" |  head -n 1
which nvcc | sed "s/\/bin\/nvcc//"
which nvcc | head -c -10
```

They are all PATH-based. One could locate libraries instead.
It would be more robust if there are no CUDA paths in PATH.

I'm using this in a Makefile.

Comment: You have to strip "bin" from that. Anyway, my collegue uses Netbeans and he doesn't have cuda in his PATH at all. A non path-based technique would be more robust.

Comment: how about `$ locate cuda`  and parsing the rest?

Comment: @Georges Parsing the output of `locate` does not look particularly robust (for most patters you can imagine a false positive e.g. from a custom installation) and requires mlocate to be installed and running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How does something based on`ldconfig -p | grep libcuda` sound ? Considering [an appropriate ldconfig setup](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) is explicitly advised at the end of the installation of the CUDA toolkit, it should do the trick without path nicely, I think.

Comment: So that's how one can obtain the pure path: "dirname `dirname `ldconfig -p | grep libcudart | awk '{print $4}' | head -n 1` | head -c -5". This is more robust than the PATH-based approach. However, it is working on a Linux box but not on a Mac. No ldconfig on MAC?

Comment: Oops, I should have asked: Locate CUDA installation path on Unix. For linux this is probably the best way.